# LSTM time-series model is acting bipolar/what is the right model to use on this data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, keras, lstm

I'm working on this machine learning model to help predict time series data.

I have sequences of data:

- multiple features at each time step
- an output consisting of an array of two values at the end of the sequence. These outputs are binary "[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1]" etc...

I train the model in batches of 1000 data points with sequences of shape (1000, 20).

I thought using an LSTM (80) with a Dense Layer at the end would do the trick. But as I train the model, it behaves very bipolar. Every train test the accuracy is either 95.~% accurate, or 27.~% accurate.

See Below:

Here's my model in Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(80,input_shape=(1000, 20), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here's my data:

Input:

> Shape (1001, 1000, 20)

Output:

> Shape (1001, 1000, 2)

Note:

(I'm actually only interested in the last value of the (1000, 2)) - What is the value at the end, when the entire sequence is processed?

Here's the behavior I see (Note accuracies):

> 1001/1001 [==============================] - 94s 94ms/step - loss: 6.9542e-04 - acc: 0.6398
>
> Epoch 98/100
>
> 1001/1001 [==============================] - 95s 95ms/step - loss: 7.2331e-04 - acc: 0.6206
>
> Epoch 99/100
>
> 1001/1001 [==============================] - 93s 93ms/step - loss: 7.6055e-04 - acc: 0.6356
>
> Epoch 100/100
>
> 1001/1001 [==============================] - 93s 93ms/step - loss: 6.1643e-04 - acc: 0.6365
>
> 1001/1001 [==============================] - 8s 8ms/step
>
> Model accuracy: 25.06%
>
> Model loss: 0.07%

-------- OR ---------

> Epoch 97/100
>
> 1001/1001 [==============================] - 95s 94ms/step - loss: 6.9479e-04 - acc: 0.6324
>
> Epoch 98/100
>
> 1001/1001 [==============================] - 94s 94ms/step - loss: 6.5280e-04 - acc: 0.6274
>
> Epoch 99/100
>
> 1001/1001 [==============================] - 94s 94ms/step - loss: 7.5665e-04 - acc: 0.6399
>
> Epoch 100/100
>
> 1001/1001 [==============================] - 93s 93ms/step - loss: 7.5244e-04 - acc: 0.6401
>
> 1001/1001 [==============================] - 8s 8ms/step
>
> Model accuracy: 95.28%
>
> Model loss: 0.06%

Questions:

1) Am I using the right model?

2) What can I do to improve my prediction?

3) What other models should I try?

Thanks so much in Advance!

Comment: your article about the vr is amazing. I read it in Medium. Can't wait for the second post :P